# Kotlin: How to save an arraylist in SharedPreferences

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences, moshi

I created an android app with kotlin, in this app i use a WS that provides all the list of products. So, how can i save the list of products in SharedPreferences with a moshi library?
Here's my code:

```
fun setArrayDataBykeyValue(context: Context, key: String, DataArrayList: Array<ProductData>) {
    val gson = Gson()
    val jsonString = gson.toJson(DataArrayList)
    val sp = context.getSharedPreferences(context.packageName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    sp.edit().putString(key, jsonString).commit()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you can do it.

```
Moshi moshi = new Moshi.Builder().build();
Type type = Types.newParameterizedType(List.class, Person.class);
JsonAdapter< List > jsonAdapter = moshi.adapter(type);
String json = jsonAdapter.toJson(body.getParams());
```

where *Person* is your POJO or some model class.

and then save this string in shared preference and do the reverse like this to get back in List

```
List<Person> persons = jsonAdapter.fromJson(json);
```

Answer (score 2):

I know you are asking for Moshi library, but I want provide you my **Kotlin** extension functions for working with `ArrayList` as saved in SharedPreferences using Gson.

I think it's easy to convert this to using Moshi library and it's very useful.

```
inline fun <reified T> SharedPreferences.addItemToList(spListKey: String, item: T) {
    val savedList = getList<T>(spListKey).toMutableList()
    savedList.add(item)
    val listJson = Gson().toJson(savedList)
    edit { putString(spListKey, listJson) }
}

inline fun <reified T> SharedPreferences.removeItemFromList(spListKey: String, item: T) {
    val savedList = getList<T>(spListKey).toMutableList()
    savedList.remove(item)
    val listJson = Gson().toJson(savedList)
    edit {
        putString(spListKey, listJson)
    }
}

fun <T> SharedPreferences.putList(spListKey: String, list: List<T>) {
    val listJson = Gson().toJson(list)
    edit {
        putString(spListKey, listJson)
    }
}

inline fun <reified T> SharedPreferences.getList(spListKey: String): List<T> {
    val listJson = getString(spListKey, "")
    if (!listJson.isNullOrBlank()) {
        val type = object : TypeToken<List<T>>() {}.type
        return Gson().fromJson(listJson, type)
    }
    return listOf()
}
```

Comment: thansk a lot bro, it worked for me. this line did the trick. val type = object : TypeToken<List<T>>() {}.type

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) library for this.

At first, you have to convert the ArrayList to string. For example:

```
val arrayString = Gson().toJson(arrayList)
```

Then, you can store the string in SharedPreference. To retrieve the String, you have to retrieve the String first and then convert it again to ArrayList. For example:

```
val collectionType = object : TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {}.type
arrayList = Gson().fromJson(arrayString, collectionType)
```

Let me know if you face any problem in this regard.